# how to display pop up only 1 time in 1 day using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popup

i have a code like this. i want to showing that pop up only 1 time in 1 day.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup = function() {
        window.open ("http://example.com", "Window","status=1,toolbar=1");
    }
</script>
<body onclick="popup()">    </body>
```

that code will open pop up when i click anywhere on the page but it will always pop up a window everytime i click, so i want to make that pop up only showing 1 time in 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the `last-shown` time-stamp in `localstorage` and compare the same with current time-stamp (after stripping off hours/min/sec/ms)

**Demo** (*please check locally only*)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var popup = function() {
    var lastShownTs = +localStorage.getItem("lastShown");
    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var lastShown = null;
    if (!isNaN(lastShownTs)) {
      lastShown = new Date(lastShownTs);
      lastShown.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (lastShown == null || lastShown.getTime() != currentDate.getTime()) {
      window.open("http://example.com", "Window", "status=1,toolbar=1");
      localStorage.setItem("lastShown", currentDate.getTime());
    }
  }
</script>

<body onclick="popup()"> </body>
```

Comment: what mean of `currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` and `lastShown.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`  i try run from Try Editor w3School and it working. so if pop up show on Saturday 24.00 PM and the next pop up will show again in sunday 24.00 PM?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to ensure that only date part can be compared to each other, and rest of the timestamp is not considered.

Comment: thanks for u code. i need it to get cache. so visitor will not get error page at first come.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage or cookies to store the time when the popup was last shown. If the difference between the current time and the last time is greater than 24 hours, you will render the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LocalStorage of browser, to know what user see the popup and never show more once a day.

You can use:

```
localStorage.setItem('PopupName', 'true')
localStorage.getItem('PopupName') // that return true
```

With this you can invoke a function that checks if that variable already exists in LocalStorage, and if it does not exist, execute the code that shows the popup and set a variable in LocalStorage like the example.